# Mixed Strategy subgame perfect equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZA8g.png)

If player I can commit to a mixed strategy (1-p,p) for strategies (A,B) and player II knows the probability (1-p,p) applied to both strategies, what is the value of p in a subgame perfect equilibrium?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the probability must make player 2 indifferent between playing either strategies $p$ and $q$, or strategies $p$ and $r$.

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't that be a mixed NE? (not necessarily an SPNE).

Comment: @Maths: You're showing a strategic form game, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about SPNE since there is no subgame there.